# How to check for a pattern saved in $var for presence at the end of $str ? Both variables have special characters

Tags: regex, perl

In perl, if I have a string `$str` and a pattern saved in `$pat` and I want to replace what is saved in `$pat` with `'nothing'` only if `$pat` appears at the end of `$str`, how would the regular expression look like? I tried different versions of this - `s/\$pat$//`

That, and all variations( `s/$pat$//`, `s/\${pat}$//`, `s/${pat}$//`) are not working :|

```
my $str = " aaa.::aa*bb/bb*cc:1/cc\n xxx.::xx*yy/yy*zz:1/xx\n";

my $pat = "xxx.::xx*yy/yy*zz:1/xx";

$str =~ s/$pat\n$//;

print $str;
```

Comment: s/$pat$// works for me.  U may need to provide more code with the problem you're seeing

Comment: $str =~ s/\Q$pat\E\n$//;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment this is what "works" for me:

```
my $pat = 'this';
my $string = 'not this but this';
$string =~ s/$pat$//;
say $string;

# outputs "not this but"
```

**Update using your new example**

What u need is [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for it to work:

```
my $str = " aaa.::aa*bb/bb*cc:1/cc\n xxx.::xx*yy/yy*zz:1/xx\n";
my $pat = quotemeta "xxx.::xx*yy/yy*zz:1/xx";

$str =~ s/$pat\n$//;

print $str;

# now prints : aaa.::aa*bb/bb*cc:1/cc\n
```

Answer (score 2):

If your pattern contains special regex characters, you need to tell Perl to treat them as literals -- for example, by using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
my $str = " aaa.::aa*bb/bb*cc:1/cc\n xxx.::xx*yy/yy*zz:1/xx\n";
my $pat =                           "xxx.::xx*yy/yy*zz:1/xx";

$pat = quotemeta $pat;
$str =~ s/$pat$/NOTHING/;

print $str;
```

If you don't want to modify `$pat` using `quotemeta`, you can also use the `\Q` and `\E` escape characters, which apply `quotemeta` to the enclosed portion of the pattern.

```
$str =~ s/\Q$pat\E$/NOTHING/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide some more code. The following works just fine for me:

```
my $pat = 'foo';
my $str = 'barbarfoo';

$str =~ s/.+\Q$pat\E$/nothing/;

print $str, "\n";
```

Edit: After receiving a helpful comment, I added quoting with `\Q` and `\E` to the above regular expression.

Comment: I have '/' in both $pat and $str. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

$pat = 'some/foo:more/foo'; 
$str = "some/str:more/str\nsome/foo:more/foo";

Comment: Thanks for letting me/us know. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
$str =~ s/$pat$//;
```